# How to customize the HTML5 input range type looks using CSS?

Tags: css, html, progress-bar, input-type-range

I want to customize the looks of the range input type in HTML5 to look something like a progress bar. I've tried applying some common CSS attributes using CSS class but it seems that they are not working.

Can any one direct me how to customize it??

Comment: With a combination of javascript? Through CSS, you could have the input not displayed and render wathever's suited :before and :after the element. Then through javascript handle how all that interract with each other.

Comment: Here is an excellent article on this subject: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-range-slider-style/.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd unaccept the currently accepted answer (and perhaps accept another one that you like). Having an answer saying "don't even try this, the technology is too new" from *5 years ago* still pinned to the top of the answer list helps nobody.

Comment: This is a little old but still pops up in the search engines so - here is a good example of implementation and x-browser http://brennaobrien.com/blog/2014/05/style-input-type-range-in-every-browser.html .  Nothing wrong with the accepted answer, its just a bit out of date.

Comment: Is there a javascript-based way to do this programmatically?  I'm interested in dynamically modifying the attributes of the thumb element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT**: nowadays all major browser support both

- [<progress>](https://caniuse.com/#search=range)
- [input[type='range']](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#range-state-(type%3Drange))

Hence **you should use one of these two, as explained in other answers**, and this should not be the accepted answer anymore.

---

The `<input type="range">` is pretty new and you are already attempting to customize it with CSS. :)

I wouldn't try that for two reasons:

1. there **might be huge compatibility issues now and for the next few (or many) years**.
   Think that in nowadays a form control like `<select>` (available since the web started) is still problematic to be customized with CSS in a cross browser way. For instance if you set a `padding` for the select boxes, many browser (IE7, OPERA9, CHROME5, SAFARI4) will totally ignore the padding.
   It works only IE8 and on FF 3.6. (all tests done with HTML5 DOCTYPE so in standard mode).
2. The `<input type="range">` has been created to **show a slider NOT a progress bar**, attempting to cheat on it with CSS in order to transform a slider into progress bar it sounds bizarre. Like trying to use CSS to change a `<textarea>` into a table, but why don't you simply use a `<table>` to render tables?!

To show a progress bar in HTML5 you should follow the suggestion given by *marcgg* in his answer. Since no browser is currently rendereing it you could use a simple div with a p inside like this:

```
<div id="progress" style="position:relative; width:100px; height:20px; border:1px solid #cccccc;">
   <p style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; background-color:#0000ff; height:100%; width:30%; font-size:0px;">&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Then simply update the `style.width` of inner `P` element in percent like:

```
width: 75%
```

FYI: if you want to do that in simple JS here is the code:

```
document.getElementById('progress').(getElementsByTagName('p')[0]).style.width = '75%';
```

Comment: well I don't exactly know what's the best option to do. I read a tutorial on HTML5 audio tag and there they'd used the input range type to show the progress of the audio being played. So I just want to customize the looks.
Any suggestions on what to use for the same???

Comment: The suggestion of what to use for the same is in my answer! Use a DIV with a P inside. It shows a progress bar, if you don't believe me, just copy and paste the code in a page and try it. Do you have the link of the tutorial? It seesm odd they suggest to modify via CSS a slider to turn it in a progress bar, it's odd! A slider is something the user can interact with by moving the slider, a progress bar is something the user can only see and not change by moving the mouse over it.

Comment: well thank you very much. I think I'll be using your suggestion. And well it's from http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/. Actually they didn't suggest to change it using CSS. They were just using the slider bar but then I don't like the looks so I thought if I could just change it using CSS since I know a little bit of it :)

Comment: -1. Answers about 'this is new' are terrible: these days most browsers support HTML5 'range' and 'progress' inputs, and the correct answer is below, but this answer from 2010 about 'don't do that' is still marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: @nailer: it's still not supported on IE8/IE9 (see here http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-range ) and they still make for the 15% of browser usage (see http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201309-201311-bar ) also still partially supported on Android up to 4.1. If you sell something online with an ecommerce site, would it be worth to loose 15% of your potential customers' base because of an `<input type="range">`?

Comment: using a slider as a progress bar is not such a terrible idea at all, and it's NOT the same as using a textarea to mimic a table (how would you do that exactly ?), + if you know what platform your site runs on you can use the new tags,(it could for example be limited to mobile phones, or even on type of mobile phone) + sometimes it's just good to do away with the past, it's about time that people use good web browers (instead of IE)

Comment: BTW, IE11's range control looks like it is a combination of a progress bar and slider. [Try it yourself](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_range), [SNAPSHOT](http://snag.gy/fFsCc.jpg)

Answer (score 70):

```
input[type='range'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background:red;
    height:7px;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background:blue;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
}
```

Comment: This works on iOS 5.0 too, which is nice because the default is pretty small for a touch device.

Answer (score 24):

If you're using HTML 5, why not use the `progress` tag?

```
<progress value="1534602" max="4603807">33%</progress>
```

Comment: Is there any browser able to render this?

Comment: I don't think any browser yet renders this, maybe http://www.modernizr.com/ can help?

Comment: @MarcoDemaio Firefox, Safari and Chrome render it

Comment: @cofiem Modernizer doesn't help unsupported browsers render new features, it only detects if they support the feature or not.

Comment: progress and input[type=range] have different uses, only range is designed for user input.

Comment: That is not really an input

Answer (score 14):

I did a cross-browser solution (+IE9, FF, Chrome, Safari), only CSS.

**[Updated 24.11.2016]**

http://codepen.io/nlfonseca/pen/MwbovQ

```css
@import 'bourbon';

$slider-width-number: 240;
$slider-width: #{$slider-width-number}px;
$slider-height: 2px;
$background-slider: #c7c7c7;
$background-filled-slider: #e33d44;
$thumb-width: 28px;
$thumb-height: 18px;
$thumb-radius: 8px;
$thumb-background: #fff;
$thumb-border: 1px solid #777;
$shadow-size: -8px;
$fit-thumb-in-slider: -8px;

@function makelongshadow($color, $size) {
  $val: 5px 0 0 $size $color;

  @for $i from 6 through $slider-width-number {
    $val: #{$val}, #{$i}px 0 0 $size #{$color};
  }

  @return $val;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  align-items: center;
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: $slider-width;

  &:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: $background-filled-slider;
    content: '';
    height: $slider-height;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  &::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    @include size($thumb-width $thumb-height);

    appearance: none;
    background: $thumb-background;
    border-radius: $thumb-radius;
    box-shadow: makelongshadow($background-slider, $shadow-size);
    margin-top: $fit-thumb-in-slider;
    border: $thumb-border;
  }


  &::-moz-range-track {
    width: $slider-width;
    height: $slider-height;
  }

  &::-moz-range-thumb {
    @include size($thumb-width $thumb-height);

    background: $thumb-background;
    border-radius: $thumb-radius;
    border: $thumb-border;
    position: relative;
  }

  &::-moz-range-progress {
    height: $slider-height;
    background: $background-filled-slider;
    border: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  &::-ms-track {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    color: transparent;
    height: $slider-height;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: $slider-width;
  }

  &::-ms-thumb {
    @include size($thumb-width $thumb-height);

    background: $thumb-background;
    border-radius: $thumb-radius;
    border: $thumb-border;
  }

  &::-ms-fill-lower {
    background: $background-filled-slider;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  &::-ms-fill-upper {
    background: $background-slider;
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  &::-ms-tooltip {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a clever attempt and the response that most closely answers the question. But there are issues with it: it essentially works by elongating the slider control (thumb?). This is fine for dragging but you can only click to set the position of the bar to the right of the slider. Clicking to the left doesn't do anything.

Comment: Nice catch. Thank you very much.
I already fixed this issue putting `pointer-events: none;` on the 'before' of the thumb.

The demo is already updated. ;)

Comment: wonderful solution thank you for all the effort! can't believe they didn't think of skinning a control. oh well just kidding I totally can

Comment: Yes @fedeghe. Chrome now don't allow pseudo elements on shadow elements... 
So the target "::-webkit-slider-thumb:before" doesn't exist anymore. I didn't find a way to resolve this. :/

Comment: The only real solution I found relies on js

Comment: Yes :/ what is a shame... for a little little detail on chrome and on the previous version worked :/

Comment: @fedeghe I already got another solution :)
check again the link: http://codepen.io/nlfonseca/pen/MwbovQ

Answer (score 12):

You can in Webkit, through the `-webkit-slider-thumb` pseudo-element: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/BNm8j/

```css
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: silver;
    width: 200px;
    height:20px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 10px;
    height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" />
```

Although the others are right about input `type="range"` not being the right element for the job.

You should use the `<progress>` element and for browsers that don't support it, this polyfill: http://lea.verou.me/polyfills/progress/

Comment: `input type="range"` is the right element and `progress` isn't if user input is desired.

Answer (score 6):

You can edit the CSS of the range input, using `input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb` and `input[type="range"]`.

Here is the example of it,

[http://webstutorial.com/range-input-slider-html5-css3/html-5](http://web.archive.org/web/20120407000030/http://webstutorial.com/range-input-slider-html5-css3/html-5)

I know this is already answered but just sharing it.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery Tools provides a plug-in that creates stylable elements from a range input, and what's more, makes it still work as a slider in older browsers that don't support `input[type=range]`.

Allows you to style:

- the handle
- the slider
- optional progress fill
- value output field

I've used it many times and it's a great tool.

WARNING: doesn't work on touch devices. I don't have as much experience with it, but you could try the jQuery mobile slider: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/sliders/

http://jquerytools.github.io/demos/rangeinput/index.html

Answer (score 2):

When I looked at this question I needed something simple. There are already a number of framework answers on how to do this, but sometimes it is more lightweight and flexible just to create your own. Of course, you get a certain amount for free with a framework (and it is often the right choice if it is a good fit), but you then have to worry about framework compatibility, support and digging into the depths of the framework to go outside its boundaries.

Here is a simple javascript-only slider. Basically it is an img for the slider, an img for the button and a callback with a progress percent. Not an all-singing and dancing slider, but something simple to build on.

**[The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HnyLN/)**

**The HTML**

```
<div id='bb_sliderContainer'  ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">
    <img id='bb_slider' src='slider.png'/>
    <img id='bb_sliderButton' src='sliderbutton.png'/>
</div>
```

**The script**

Place in a javascript file:

```
(function(bb,undefined){    
bb.Slider = function(buttonCssId,sliderCssId,initialPercentage,progressUpdate)
{
    var halfButtonWidth = 5;
    var sliderMoving = false;
    var buttonElement = document.getElementById(buttonCssId);
    var sliderElement = document.getElementById(sliderCssId);                
    var length = sliderElement.clientWidth;                
    var leftPos = 0;
    var rightPos = leftPos + length;
    length = rightPos - leftPos;              

    if( initialPercentage )
    {
        var buttonPos = leftPos + initialPercentage / 100 * length;
        buttonElement.style.left = buttonPos - halfButtonWidth + 'px';  
    }        

    buttonElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function(){ 
        sliderMoving = true;
    } );        

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', function(event){
        if( sliderMoving == true )
        {                      
            var rect = sliderElement.getBoundingClientRect();                                                                        
            var mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
            var prop = mouseX / length;
            if( prop < 0 )
            {
                prop = 0;
                mouseX = 0;
            }
            if( prop > 1 )
            {
                prop = 1;
                mouseX = length;
            }                
            buttonElement.style.left = leftPos + prop * length - halfButtonWidth + 'px';                
            progressUpdate(prop * 100);         
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function(){
        sliderMoving = false;
    });
}    
}(window.bb = window.bb || {}));
```

**Example use**

HTML:

```
<img src='space.png' style='width:50%;position:relative;top:20px' id='bb_sliderSubject'>
```

Javascript:

```
function sliderUpdate(percentage)
{
    var sliderSubject = document.getElementById('bb_sliderSubject');
    sliderSubject.style.width = percentage + '%';
}
window.onload=function()
{
    var slider = new bb.Slider('bb_sliderButton','bb_slider',50,sliderUpdate);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example:

```css
input[type='range'] {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #333;
 background-color: #999;
 height: 10px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-track {
 -moz-appearance: none;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #333;
 background-color: #999;
 height: 10px;
}
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
 -webkit-appearance: none !important;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(000,000,000,0.5);
 border: 1px solid #999;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-range-thumb {
 -moz-appearance: none;
 border-radius: 20px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(000,000,000,0.5);
 border: 1px solid #999;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Comment: From where did the author of the snippet get selector names like moz-range-track? Is there any possibility to find them in chrome?

Answer (score 1):

See http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/webforms/styler/index.html?range

It's a tool that produces cross-browser code to style both native and webshims range inputs like you want.

```
.ws-range, input[type="range"] {
    /* Range styles: width, height, border-radius, background */
    -webkit-appearance: none;cursor: pointer;border: 0;outline: none;padding: 0;margin: 20.5px 0;
}
.ws-range .ws-range-thumb {
    /* Thumb styles: width, height, border, border-radius, background */
}
.ws-range.ws-focus .ws-range-thumb {
    /* Thumb focus styles: border-color, background */
}
.ws-range.ws-active .ws-range-thumb {
    /* Thumb active styles: border-color, background */
}
.ws-range .ws-range-min {
    /* Thumb progress styles: display, background */
    border-radius: /* same as range */;
    height: 100%;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    border: none;background: transparent;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-tooltip {
    display: none;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    /* Thumb styles: width, height, border, border-radius, background */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
    /* Range styles: width, height, border-radius, background */
    color: transparent;border: 0;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    /* Thumb styles: width, height, border, border-radius, background */
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
    /* Thumb styles: width, height, border, border-radius, background */
}
input[type="range"]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    /* Thumb focus styles: border-color, background */
}
input[type="range"]:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
    /* Thumb focus styles: border-color, background */
}
input[type="range"]:focus::-ms-thumb {
    /* Thumb focus styles: border-color, background */
}
input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    /* Thumb active styles: border-color, background */
}
input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb {
    /* Thumb active styles: border-color, background */
}
input[type="range"]:active::-ms-thumb {
    /* Thumb active styles: border-color, background */
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    /* Thumb progress styles: display, background */
    border-radius: /* same as range */;
    height: 100%;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
    /* Thumb progress styles: display, background */
    border-radius: /* same as range */;
    height: 100%;
}
.no-cssrangeinput input[type="range"] {
    background: transparent;margin: 0;border: 0;min-height: 51px;
}
```