# Style range property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw some website where someone styled the html5 range input and changed what it's handle looked like. How could I do that? Are there CSS3 properties for it's handle, or should I make an image that covers it and stays on top with javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the HTML5  input range type looks using CSS??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556157/how-to-customize-the-html5-input-range-type-looks-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently no hooks in CSS to target the slide knob. You'd have to try hacking it with JS for now. Hopefully a future version of [CSS Basic UI](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-ui/) will define a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can in Webkit, through the :-webkit-slider-thumb pseudo-element: http://jsfiddle.net/leaverou/BNm8j/