# How to style <input type='range' /> in IE10

Tags: css, input, internet-explorer-10

I want to style the `<input type='range' />` element in IE10.

By default, IE 10 style the element like this: 
[image]

I want to customize it a bit, say, changing the color blue to red, grey to black, the little bars to yellow, the little black scrubber to white. I tried overwriting the `background-color` property and the `color` property in CSS. But it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you seen this question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556157/how-to-customize-the-html5-input-range-type-looks-using-css

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a number of pseudo elements you can use to style range controls in IE10.

```
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Will colour the part after the thumb. To style before the thumb use:

```
 input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
    background-color: lime green;
}
```

See for example http://jsfiddle.net/K8WyC/4/

To style the thumb you can use ::-ms-thumb, while the tick marks can be styled with `::-ms-ticks-before`, `::-ms-ticks-after`, or `::-ms-track` (the latter styles both sides). You can find out more about the various pseudo-elements for controls at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869604(v=vs.85).aspx

The styles you are asking for can be achieved like in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K8WyC/8/

Comment: Do you happen to know what the "drag end" event is for this `input range` element?

Comment: dragend is for HTML5 drag and drop and not the range element in particular. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/dnd.html#event-dragend

Comment: thx.. i tried it in IE and it didn't work well... ended up using `MSPointerUp`

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Microsoft CSS pseudo elements:

- ::-ms-fill-lower
- ::-ms-fill-upper
- ::-ms-thumb
- ::-ms-ticks-before
- ::-ms-ticks-after
- ::-ms-ticks
- ::-ms-tooltip

[Here the full Microsoft pseudo list...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**IE10**

[Here is a page with styled IE10 range controls](http://dev.bowdenweb.com/html/e/form/ie10-form-controls/scenario7_1.html)
(Open with IE10)

**WebKit**

[WebKit shadow DOM](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#progress_element)

**Other browsers**

[How to style range control for multiple browsers](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_range)

[A Sliding Nightmare](https://css-tricks.com/sliding-nightmare-understanding-range-input)

Answer (score 0):

in the previous answer,

```
::-ms-ticks
```

should read

```
::-ms-track
```

(which is just the ordinary track). The tick color is set by

```
::-ms-track {color:red;}
```

The tick height is the track's height, and the width cannot be set. Ticks are suppressed, as is well known, with

```
 ::-ms-track {color:transparent;}
```

The pseudo-elements

```
::-ms-ticks-before,
::-ms-ticks-after {
display:block; (or inline-block)
color:red;
height:10px;
}
```

create additional ticks above and below the track. One can set their colors and their heights. The tick widths cannot be set. *display* seems required.

Internet Explorer since IE10 does have default *vertical padding*. Top padding is 17px, bottom padding is 32px. This makes for a heigh slider by default. Therefore

```
padding:0px;
```

may be applied. 
(See https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/792971/input-type-range-has-vertical-padding-by-default .)

(As I cannot yet comment, I post like this).