# Change color of input range slider with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

How can I change the color of my slider from

```
<input type="range" id="input">
```

I already tried color, bg-color and background-color and it won't change...

UPDATE:

I wanna change it with javascript. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("input").style.background-color = "000000";
```

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556157/how-to-customize-the-html5-input-range-type-looks-using-css

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: silver;
    width: 200px;
    height:20px;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
     -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #666;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 10px;
    height: 26px;
}

document.getElementById("input").style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
```

<kbd>**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HC2Pp/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: so can I change the style of the slider thumb with javascript too?

Comment: Yes you can change background color. updated code. see fiddle for demo.

Comment: which background color you would like to change? input element with type range.. Am I right?

Comment: i want to change the slider and the background

Comment: Am not sure about slider. But you can change range element background with this code.

Comment: In my case this is not working. This is working fine on Fiddle but when i use this code in my project. It does not work. Can you please assist?

Comment: @SundeepSaluja: If you could share more info/ask new question with code that you are trying will help us to debug an issue.