# React - input range change color dynamically

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a component that contains input from the type range.
I have multiple instances of this component and on each component, I'd like to have a different color for the left side input range.

This is what I've got so far

```
  <div class={styles.bar}>
    <input
      type="range"
      style={{
        backgroundColor: props.color,
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

how can I edit the color dynamically? (I want to look exactly the same like a regular input range, but the button and left range in a different color)

[this](https://jsfiddle.net/m2pe7ty9/7/) is a fiddle of my work.

Thanks

Comment: You tried adding a state?

Comment: @DennisVash state of what? the problem is not the variable, but the input itself. the color doesn't change

Comment: Oh you mean you expect it to be 'red' and its 'blue?

Comment: @DennisVash yap.

Comment: did you try doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493591/change-color-of-input-range-slider-with-javascript)?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá this changes the whole bar. I need only the left part (the one that moves).     -webkit-appearance: none; it's a problem

Comment: Pretty sure you must to override with `-webkit-appearance`, so you can't just target the left part

Comment: You might wanna check this documentation [Link](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)

Comment: This is the closest I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38163892/863110

Comment: @KALITA Thanks. I saw some ideas there..I'm not sure if it's 100%

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks...still not the same as I need...but thanks !

Comment: It's crazy that such a simple CSS can be that complex.