# Styling input range on firefox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style the HTML input range and it works as I expected on webkit browsers but my styling for -moz- browsers doesn't seem to work. I was trying to use pseudo elements before and after on the moz-range-thumb but Firefox doesnt support that maybe? I couldn't find any proper documentation on this. But if someone can help me come up with a solution to this I'd really appreciate it.

This is the moz styling I applied which is the same as for webkit browsers:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb:before {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 5px;
                        left: -2000px;
                        width: 2000px;
                        height: 6px;
                        margin-left: -2px;
                        background: #666;
                        content: ' ';
                    }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34yp5o25/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the HTML5 input range type looks using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556157/how-to-customize-the-html5-input-range-type-looks-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

For firefox just added `background: #fff;` to `input` style and it rendered exact as chrome. if it doesn't work with you we can check your firefox version.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect explanation of the reason is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-the-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field#answer-4660434).

> **`:before` and `:after` render inside a container**
>   Pseudo-elements can only be defined (or better said are only supported) on container elements. Because the way they are rendered are **within** the container itself as a child element. `input` can not contain other elements hence they're not supported.

As a cross-browser workaround you can use the pseudo-elements on the input's `label` tag instead. That worked for me.