# customize the handler of input range

Tags: html, css

When we use input range `<input type="range"`, there is a handler which is moveable as how we handle it.

Now I need a help how to customize this handle, in this case I want to change the default handler with my own handler(image of button).

Thanks for the help

```html
<input type='range'/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize the HTML5 input range type looks using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556157/how-to-customize-the-html5-input-range-type-looks-using-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to style the base:

```
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* Hides the slider so that custom slider can be made */
  width: 100%; /* Specific width is required for Firefox. */
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none; /* Removes the blue border. You should probably do some kind of focus styling for accessibility reasons though. */
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent; /* Hides the slider so custom styles can be added */
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

Use the following to style the thumb:

```
/* Special styling for WebKit/Blink */
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -14px; /* You need to specify a margin in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE it is automatic */
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d; /* Add cool effects to your sliders! */
}

/* All the same stuff for Firefox */
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* All the same stuff for IE */
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000, 0px 0px 1px #0d0d0d;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 36px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #ac51b5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -3.6px;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #ac51b5;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #ac51b5;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #65001c;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #ac51b5;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #ac51b5;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" />
```

**Reference:** [Styling Cross-Browser Compatible Range Inputs with CSS](https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/)

Comment: Can I replace it with image or adding a text in the handler?

Comment: Yup, instead of `background-color` use `background-image`!